# Android - replace data in String

Tags: java, android, string

One more question :-)

I have a string which looks like this:

---

```
Saved
Saved
Saved
->12345678
Saved
Saved
->98765432
```

---

And I need to replace all the `->XXXXXXXX` Strings to the `CORRUPTED`. The numbers after `->` are different.
How I can do te trick?

Excuse for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is your friend:

```
String out = in.replaceAll("^\\-\\>\\d+$", "CORRUPTED");
```

This replaces everything of the form `->[numberHere]` with "CORRUPTED", using [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

- `^` matches the start of a line.
- `$` matches the end of the line.
- `\d+` matches a number of 1 or more digits.

[Rubular demo here.](http://rubular.com/r/y4x7G5IODb)